# How to I send user data to the firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a personalized users section in my firebase database. Every time a user creates an account the info will be stored. When I do the push the data is not sent to the database.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(result){ 
    console.log('result', result);
    if (result) {
      // User is signed in.
      result.updateProfile({displayName: document.getElementById("name").value});

      var user_info = {id: result.uid, email: result.email, display_name: result.displayName};
      console.log('user_info', user_info);
      // Storing user info into database.
      var database = firebase.database();

      console.log('user id', user_info.id);
      database.ref().child('users/' + user_info.id).push({
          displayName: user_info.display_name,
          id: user_info.id,
          email: user_info.email
       });

      window.location = "index.html"
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
})
```

Comment: Try seeing if an error occurred when you pushed

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition in your code.

```
window.location = "index.html"
```

The window relocation is interrupting the database write operation. You have to wait for database.ref().child('users/' + user_info.id).push to complete before you redirect.

`database.ref().child('users/' + user_info.id).push(obj).then(function() {
  window.location = "index.html"
});`